# Use one table to order another

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to make a MySQL call, where I select some sources from one table and their related articles from another, and then sort the sources by the latest article. (The date of the latest article is found by ordering the articles)

*Articles is mentioned as Newsitems in the DB*

My query looks like this at the moment

```
SELECT source.Name, source.Id, newsitem.UploadedAt 
FROM northern_light.source 
INNER JOIN northern_light.source_newsitem 
ON source.Id = source_newsitem.SourceId 
INNER JOIN northern_light.newsitem
ON source_newsitem.NewsItemId = newsitem.NewsItemId
WHERE source.Name LIKE '%%'
GROUP BY source.Id 
ORDER BY newsitem.UploadedAt DESC
LIMIT 0, 100;
```

The problem with this is that it does not select the newest 'Newsitem'.
Is there a way I can select source.name, source.id and newsitem.uploadedAt while I order DESC by newsitem.UploadedAt?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a GROUP BY after the ORDER BY by wrapping your query with the GROUP BY like this:

```
SELECT test.* FROM (
    SELECT source.Name, source.Id, newsitem.UploadedAt 
    FROM northern_light.source 
    INNER JOIN northern_light.source_newsitem 
    ON source.Id = source_newsitem.SourceId 
    INNER JOIN northern_light.newsitem
    ON source_newsitem.NewsItemId = newsitem.NewsItemId
    WHERE source.Name LIKE '%%'
    ORDER BY newsitem.UploadedAt DESC
    LIMIT 0, 100
) AS test GROUP BY source.Id;
```

Comment: Changing the "AS test GROUP BY source.Id" to "AS test GROUP BY Id" Did it. Thank you very much... Highly appreciated.